# While converting Jenkins declarative pipeline script to normal pipeline script not working(pipeline to node)

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is the pipeline script for build report to the developer who committed last. And this script is absolutely working.

But for some reason they asked me to convert this script to a normal pipeline script. When i tried to convert the same script it is not at all working.

Please help me with this.

**Declarative pipeline**

```
pipeline {                                                                        
    agent any                                                                        
    environment {                                                                       
        LAST_COMMITER_EMAIL = sh (                                                                 
        script: 'git --no-pager show -s --format=\'%ae\'',                                                    
        returnStdout: true                                                                                                                                                                                    
        ).trim()
    }                                                                              

    stages {
        stage ('Checkout & Preparation') {
            steps {
                echo "${LAST_COMMITER_EMAIL}, xyz@company.com"
            }                                                                       
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            echo "${LAST_COMMITER_EMAIL}, xyz@company.com"
            mail to: "${LAST_COMMITER_EMAIL}", cc:'xyz@company.com, xyz@company.com', subject:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}"
        }
        failure {
            echo "${LAST_COMMITER_EMAIL}, 'xyz@company.com"
            mail to: "${LAST_COMMITER_EMAIL}", cc:'xyz@company.com, xyz@company.com', subject:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}"
        }
    }      
}
```

This is my declarative pipeline script which is working and now i want to convert it into a pipeline script.

This script will send the build success/failure report to the developer who last committed to that repository. I tried but it was not working. Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you format your code properly and add some information to it? Thanks.

Comment: Thnak you mate. Let me know if any changes required.